# How do I have circle bounce back up after gravity takes it down?

Tags: python, pygame

I have a ball and once it hits the floor, I want it to bounce back up to say half the original bounce, until it can't bounce anymore. I added a pass where the ball just stops at the bottom. How do I make it bounce back up?

```
kickoff_location = [WIDTH/2 - ball_size[0] / 2, 210]
gravity = 2
ball_bounce = False

if not(ball_bounce):
    if kickoff_location[1] < player_one_pos[1] + (player_width / 2) + ball_size[0]:
        kickoff_location[1] += gravity
    elif kickoff_location[1] == player_one_pos[1] + (player_width / 2) + ball_size[0]:
        kickoff_location[1] -= gravity / 2
        pass
```

Comment: I would use variable with `speed` and gravity should change this speed. And when it touch floor then I would change speed to negative value so it would move in different direction.

Comment: BTW: PyGame has `pygame.Rect` to keep object's size and position and `Rect` has methods to check collision with other `Rect` or point (ie. when you mouse click on button).

Comment: In addition to what @furas had already said, after setting the speed to negative, you might want to multiply it by a factor between [0, 1]. This corresponds to elasticity. 1 obviously means perfectly elastic and the speed will be retained and the ball will never stop bouncing. 0 does the opposite. Setting the value between 0 and 1 will simulate the ball losing energy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a speed vector for your ball, ie. `vel = [0, 0] # [dX, dY]`

You need simple gravity acceleration constant, ie. `grav = 0.1`

You need enviroment resistance constant, ie. `resist = 0.8`

You need mentioned elasticity factor, ie. `elast = 0.5`

Now, in every update cycle you:

- update Y part of velocity by gravity: `vel[1] += grav`
- update both velocity parts by resistance: `vel[0] *= resist ; vel[1] *= resist`
- check for collisions, vertical and horizontal separately. If collision is vertical (floor/ceiling) reverse Y speed and modify it by elasticity: `vel[1] = -vel[1] * elast`. The same for horizontal collisions, but for X part of velocity.
- update ball position by speed vector: `ball_loc[0] += vel[0] ; ball_loc[1] += vel[1]`

And tinker with constants to get realistic ball movement...

Comment: elast must be sqrt(0.5) when you want reach half height after the bounce